# JQM (jQueryMobile) Problem with form submission returned page

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery-mobile, submission

I'm following the documentation from JQM on [Submitting Forms](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html#../../docs/api/../../docs/forms/forms-sample.html) and that part is working just fine. I can see the results page as in the example. (here is the [form-sample-response.php](https://github.com/jriggins/jquery-mobile/blob/c910f4b01fcd88acf5ea3794233f2f6d6a8c18ce/docs/forms/forms-sample-response.php) page)

What my problem is:

I need to serve up another form and need the JQM functionality to work on the AJAX returned form. I have seen people say you need to add the rel="external" tag and I have done so to the page, form and button with no results.

I have even tried adding the jQuery functionality to the main form and still no go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if someone else needs this:

This goes in the main script;

```
$('#page_name_here').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    alert('This page was just hidden: '+ ui.prevPage);

    // add you other functions here
});
```

And in the form submission returned page make sure you have a corresponding id